# Where to store static contents for home/index page

Tags: playframework

I'm developing a vehicle portal using Play framework and most of the search-display-paginate functionality has been implemented. I'm a bit confused when it comes to designing the home page with caching in mind.

The home page will be a mix of pure static and dynamic contents. But the dynamic contents (such as reports, market trends and other user posted blogs, adv pictures, etc) itself might not get updated/added every day. I can think of two options:

1. To have static home.html page with all contents and modify the page when the content get updated.
2. To have home.html get dynamically rendered from the content stored in Database.

My questions are:

1. Which one is more graceful? and usually more of a standard practice ? Is there any other way can anyone suggest ?
2. Is there a way to integrate CMS systems to manage these contents along with Play-framework? or Should I develop one basic CMS with Play! and integrate.
3. Does using CMS just to manage home page seems to be a standard way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preference here would to build a dynamic home page, that uses the Cache function within Play to improve performance.

Although you can (and there are examples of this already done with Play) where a CMS has been integrated, I think it sounds overkill for your needs. Where as the dynamic part of your page does not sound too large, so maintaining it in a simple database should be pretty simple.

To Cache your homepage, you can use the `@CacheFor` annotation against the controller action.

```
@CacheFor("1h") public static void home() {

// ... your home page controller code here

}
```

This will mean any DB code etc that occurs will only execute once per hour, and the output will be cached.

Comment: Thanks! Also I'm interested in having a hook/CacheId in update/add controller so that I would be able to clear the cache off whenever the content gets updated. Does @CacheFor exposes any such Id ? or any alternatives ?

Comment: I figured this out, yes @CacheFor exposes an Id field and I've tried out a sample, worked like a charm. This is another example which shows Play offered almost everything just the way we expected it to be, most intuitive manner.